# Kivy: when to use ObjectProperty

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.6, kivy-language, object-property

I have a button (`button_child_A`) which calls a def with `on_press`. 
In this def, I want to change the text of 3 labels:

```
- `label_child_A` is in the same class as the `button_child_A`
- `label_parent`  is in the parent class of `button_child_A`
- `label_child_B` is in the sister class of `button_child_A` (same parent class)
```

I can modify `label_child_A` and `label_parent` by simply calling then with their `ids`, but I can't modify `label_child_B` by calling its `id`, I get the error:`"object has no attribute"`.   (cf `def change_label`s in the `.py` below)

I understand I have to create an `ObjectProperty` but why? Why I do not need `ObjectProperty` when I change a widget from the same class or a parent class but I need it when I change widget from a "sister class" (same parent)?

The `.py`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class Class_Parent(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Class_Child_A(BoxLayout):
    def change_labels(self):
        self.ids.label_child_A.text = "changed"
        self.parent.ids.label_parent.text= "changed"
        #self.parent.ids.classAb_id.label_child_B.text = "changed"  ## get the error 'Class_Child_B' object has no attribute 'label_child_B'
        self.parent.ids.classAb_id.label_child_b_object_property.text = "changed"   # why do I need to use ObjectProperty here ?  
    pass


class Class_Child_B(BoxLayout):
    child_b_label_object_property = ObjectProperty(None)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Class_Parent()
TestApp().run()
```

And the `.kv`:

```
<Class_Parent>:
    Label:
        id: label_parent
        text: "label parent"
    Class_Child_A:
        id: classAa_id
    Class_Child_B:
        id: classAb_id


<Class_Child_A>:
    Button:
        id: button_child_A
        text: "button child A"
        on_press: root.change_labels()

    Label:
        id: label_child_A
        text: "label child A"

<Class_Child_B>:
    label_child_b_object_property: label_child_B
    Label:
        id: label_child_B
        text: "label child B"
```